# XSLT read/change result tree while creating

Tags: xslt, resultset

I'm trying to create a list of items in a variable and want to check whether the item is already in the list or not.
The items are given by a input document which is not really important for my question.

So there are two problems I'm trying to solve.

1: read data from the variable which I'm currently generating

2: append text to a node in the variable

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
<xsl:variable name="data">
    <list>
        <xsl:call-template name="generate"/>
    </list>
</xsl:variable>


<xsl:template name="generate" match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//thing"/>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="//thing">
    <xsl:variable name="temp">
        <xsl:value-of select="./text()"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:choose>
        <!-- test however this thing is already in $data -->
        <!-- problem #1: here, trying to read anything out of $data doesn't work -->
        <xsl:when test="contains($data/list/item/text(), $temp/text())">
            <xsl:for-each select="$data/list/item">
                <xsl:if test="contains(./text(), $temp/text())">
                    <!-- problem #2: append any string to self::node()/text() -->
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <item>
                <xsl:value-of name="$temp/text()"/>
            </item>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

I've searched a lot for result tree fragment and so on, but didn't get any idea how to do that.

edit:
This should be the input code:

```
<data>
<thing>string1</thing>
<thing>string2</thing>
<thing>string3</thing>
<nested><thing>string1</thing></nested>
<nested><thing>string1</thing></nested>
<nested><thing>string2</thing></nested>
</data>
```

output:

```
<list>
<item>string1 string1 string1</item>
<item>string2 string2</item>
<item>string3</item>
</list>
```

Chris

Comment: Consider to post a sample of the XML input you have and the corresponding output you want to create, then we can suggest an XSLT approach to achieve this. I am afraid your current problem description is too procedural, XSLT is a declarative language.

Comment: Well, it's not that easy to post a sample input as my input file is very complex so I tried to keep that sample code small. I'll try...

Comment: Please try. Or read up on grouping in XSLT (XSLT 1.0: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.xml, XSLT 2.0: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#grouping-examples), my current guess is that is the XSLT approach you need/want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is my answer ( independently from Martin Honen), but I **realize that it doesn't answer your main question** -- how to traverse a tree and process and accumulate data where the processing also uses the already accumulated data. I provide this wanted solution in the second part of my answer..

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kThingByVal" match="thing"
  use="."/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <list>
      <xsl:apply-templates select=
      "//thing
          [generate-id()
          =
           generate-id(key('kThingByVal', .)[1])
          ]
      ">
      </xsl:apply-templates>
     </list>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="thing">
  <item>
   <xsl:apply-templates mode="gen"
        select="key('kThingByVal', .)"/>
  </item>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="thing" mode="gen">
  <xsl:if test="not(position() = 1)">
   <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<data>
    <thing>string1</thing>
    <thing>string2</thing>
    <thing>string3</thing>
    <nested>
        <thing>string1</thing>
    </nested>
    <nested>
        <thing>string1</thing>
    </nested>
    <nested>
        <thing>string2</thing>
    </nested>
</data>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<list>
   <item>string1 string1 string1</item>
   <item>string2 string2</item>
   <item>string3</item>
</list>
```

**II. General solution of the class of problems this problem falls into**:

We want to be able to process trees in the same way we process lists with functions like `f:foldl()` from FXSL.

**Here is the classic application showing how `f:foldl()`** (in case of XSLT 1.0 this is a template, not an `xsl:function`) can process any list with any function that takes the current accumulated result and the curent list-item and produces the new result:

**testFoldl.xsl**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:f="http://fxsl.sf.net/"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:foldr-func="foldr-func"
exclude-result-prefixes="xsl f foldr-func"
>

   <xsl:import href="foldl.xsl"/>

   <!-- This transformation must be applied to:
        numList.xml 
     -->
   <foldr-func:foldr-func/>
   <xsl:variable name="vFoldrFun" select="document('')/*/foldr-func:*[1]"/>
    <xsl:output  encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">

      <xsl:call-template name="foldl">
        <xsl:with-param name="pFunc" select="$vFoldrFun"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="pList" select="/*/*"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="pA0" select="0"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template mode="f:FXSL"
      match="foldr-func:*">
         <xsl:param name="arg1" select="0"/>
         <xsl:param name="arg2" select="0"/>

         <xsl:value-of select="$arg1 + $arg2"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on this XML document** (representing a list of numbers):

```
<nums>
  <num>01</num>
  <num>02</num>
  <num>03</num>
  <num>04</num>
  <num>05</num>
  <num>06</num>
  <num>07</num>
  <num>08</num>
  <num>09</num>
  <num>10</num>
</nums>
```

**the wanted result (the sum of all list-items) is produced**:

```
55
```

Do note, that if we pass as parameter not the `add()` function, but the `mult()` function (and remove the `0` from the list, specify a new "zero" parameter -- `1` -- the neutral number for multiplication, we will get the product of all list items -- `10!` (ten factorial).

Therefore, `f:foldl()` is a very powerful function that can be used for processing any lists where based on the accumulated result and the current list-item, a new result is produced.

If this topic seems interesting to you, there is a lot more interesting stuff **[here](http://conferences.idealliance.org/extreme/html/2006/Novatchev01/EML2006Novatchev01.html)**.

**Interestingly enough, there exists a similar function that processes a tree**:

**fold-tree2.xsl**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:f="http://fxsl.sf.net/"
 xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common"
 exclude-result-prefixes="f ext msxsl xsl"
>
 <xsl:template name="foldl-tree2">
  <xsl:param name="pFuncNode" select="/.."/>
  <xsl:param name="pFuncSubtrees" select="/.."/>
  <xsl:param name="pA0"/>
  <xsl:param name="pNode" select="/.."/>

  <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="not($pNode)">
            <xsl:copy-of select="$pA0"/>
   </xsl:when>

   <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:variable name="vSubtrees" select="$pNode/*"/>

    <xsl:variable name="vSubTreeResult">
      <xsl:call-template name="foldl-tree_">
        <xsl:with-param name="pFuncNode" select="$pFuncNode"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="pFuncSubtrees" select="$pFuncSubtrees"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="pA0" select="$pA0"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="pSubTrees" select="$vSubtrees"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:apply-templates select="$pFuncNode[1]" mode="f:FXSL">
     <xsl:with-param name="arg0" select="$pFuncNode[position() > 1]"/>
     <xsl:with-param name="arg1" select="$pNode"/>
     <xsl:with-param name="arg2" select="ext:node-set($vSubTreeResult)"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
   </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="foldl-tree_">
  <xsl:param name="pFuncNode" select="/.."/>
  <xsl:param name="pFuncSubtrees" select="/.."/>
  <xsl:param name="pA0"/>
  <xsl:param name="pSubTrees" select="/.."/>

  <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="not($pSubTrees)">
            <xsl:copy-of select="$pA0"/>
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:variable name="vSubTree1Result">
        <xsl:call-template name="foldl-tree2">
          <xsl:with-param name="pFuncNode" select="$pFuncNode"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="pFuncSubtrees" select="$pFuncSubtrees"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="pA0" select="$pA0"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="pNode" select="$pSubTrees[1]"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:variable>

      <xsl:variable name="vRestSubtreesResult">
        <xsl:call-template name="foldl-tree_">
          <xsl:with-param name="pFuncNode" select="$pFuncNode"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="pFuncSubtrees" select="$pFuncSubtrees"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="pA0" select="$pA0"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="pSubTrees" select="$pSubTrees[position() > 1]"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:variable>

     <xsl:apply-templates select="$pFuncSubtrees" mode="f:FXSL">
      <xsl:with-param name="arg0" select="$pFuncSubtrees[position() > 1]"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="arg1" select="ext:node-set($vSubTree1Result)"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="arg2" select="ext:node-set($vRestSubtreesResult)"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
   </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>    
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here, besides tree, the zero (initial result) and the function to process each tree-node (together with the accumulated result), we also pass as a parameter a function that takes the set of all subtrees of a tree-node and the accumulated result so far, and produces a new result. Also, we must pass as a parameter the top node of the tree.

**Here is a simple illustration of using `foldl-tree2()`:**

**test-foldlTree2.xsl**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:add-tree="add-tree"
 xmlns:f="http://fxsl.sf.net/"
 exclude-result-prefixes="xsl f add-tree"
>
    <xsl:import href="foldl-tree2.xsl"/>

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <add-tree:add-tree/>

    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:variable name="vAdd" select="document('')/*/add-tree:*[1]"/>

      <xsl:call-template name="foldl-tree2">
        <xsl:with-param name="pFuncNode" select="$vAdd"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="pFuncSubtrees" select="$vAdd"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="pA0" select="0"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="pNode" select="/*"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="add-tree:*" mode="f:FXSL">
      <xsl:param name="arg1"/>
      <xsl:param name="arg2"/>

      <xsl:variable name="varg1">
        <xsl:call-template name="nodeValue">
         <xsl:with-param name="pNode" select="$arg1"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:variable>

      <xsl:variable name="varg2">
        <xsl:call-template name="accumValue">
         <xsl:with-param name="pAccum" select="$arg2"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:variable>

      <xsl:value-of select="$varg1 + $varg2"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="nodeValue">
     <xsl:param name="pNode"/>
     <xsl:call-template name="toNumber">
      <xsl:with-param name="pX" select="$pNode/text()[1]"/>
     </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="accumValue">
     <xsl:param name="pAccum"/>
     <xsl:call-template name="toNumber">
      <xsl:with-param name="pX" select="$pAccum"/>
     </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="toNumber">
     <xsl:param name="pX"/>

     <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="not(number($pX) = number($pX))">0</xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
       <xsl:value-of select="number($pX)"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
     </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on any tree some of whose text nodes contain numbers**:

```
<nums>
  <a>
   <b>
    <num>01</num>
   </b>
  </a>
  <c>
   <num>02</num>
   <num>03</num>
   <num>04</num>
   <d>
    <num>05</num>
    <num>06</num>
   </d>
  </c>
  <num>07</num>
  <num>08</num>
  <num>09</num>
  <num>10</num>
</nums>
```

**it produces the sum of all such numbers**:

```
55
```

Now, we only need to pass different parameters to `foldl-tree2()` and it will extract a list of the occurencies of all `thing` element values, with all identical values under a separate `item`, as required by the original problem:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common"
 xmlns:merge-list="merge-list"
 xmlns:f="http://fxsl.sf.net/"
 exclude-result-prefixes="xsl f ext msxsl merge-list"
>
    <xsl:import href="foldl-tree2.xsl"/>

    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <merge-list:merge-list/>

    <xsl:variable name="vrtfZero">
     <list/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="vZero" select=
     "document('')/*/xsl:variable[@name='vrtfZero']/*
     "/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:variable name="vFunMerge" select="document('')/*/merge-list:*[1]"/>

      <list>
       <xsl:call-template name="foldl-tree2">
        <xsl:with-param name="pFuncNode" select="$vFunMerge"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="pFuncSubtrees" select="$vFunMerge"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="pA0" select="$vZero"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="pNode" select="/*"/>
       </xsl:call-template>
      </list>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="merge-list:*" mode="f:FXSL">
      <xsl:param name="arg1"/>
      <xsl:param name="arg2"/>

       <xsl:variable name="vrtfArg1">
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="gen" select="$arg1"/>
       </xsl:variable>

       <xsl:variable name="vrtfArg2">
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="gen" select="$arg2"/>
       </xsl:variable>

       <xsl:variable name="vArg1" select="ext:node-set($vrtfArg1)/*"/>
       <xsl:variable name="vArg2" select="ext:node-set($vrtfArg2)/*"/>

       <xsl:for-each select="$vArg1[self::thing or self::item]">
        <xsl:variable name="vMatch" select=
         "$vArg2[self::thing or self::item
               and
                 substring-before(concat(., ' '), ' ')
                =
                 substring-before(concat(current(), ' '), ' ')
                ]"/>
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="$vMatch">
            <item>
             <xsl:value-of select="$vMatch/text()"/>
             <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
             <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </item>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
           <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
       </xsl:for-each>

       <xsl:for-each select="$vArg2[self::thing or self::item]">
        <xsl:variable name="vMatch" select=
         "$vArg1[self::thing or self::item
               and
                 substring-before(concat(., ' '), ' ')
                =
                 substring-before(concat(current(), ' '), ' ')
                ]"/>
          <xsl:if test="not($vMatch)">
           <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
          </xsl:if>
       </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="thing" mode="gen">
     <item><xsl:value-of select="."/></item>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item" mode="gen">
     <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*" mode="gen"/>

    <xsl:template mode="gen" match="/">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="gen"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the originally provided XML document**:

```
<data>
    <thing>string1</thing>
    <thing>string2</thing>
    <thing>string3</thing>
    <nested>
        <thing>string1</thing>
    </nested>
    <nested>
        <thing>string1</thing>
    </nested>
    <nested>
        <thing>string2</thing>
    </nested>
</data>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<list>
   <item>string1 string1 string1</item>
   <item>string2 string2</item>
   <item>string3</item>
</list>
```

Comment: "how to traverse a tree and process and accumulate data where the processing also uses the already accumulated data" this is exactly what I'm trying :) waiting for your reply

Comment: @Chris: I was on errands early this morning. Working on this now. :)

Comment: WTH! I think this needs +1 just for the mere effort taken to actually write this answer :)

Answer (score 2):

The stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="k1" match="thing" use="."/>

  <xsl:template match="data">
    <list>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::thing[generate-id() = generate-id(key('k1', .)[1])]" mode="group"/>
    </list>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="thing" mode="group">
    <item>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('k1', .)"/>
    </item>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="thing">
    <xsl:if test="position() &gt; 1">
      <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

transforms the input

```
<data>
<thing>string1</thing>
<thing>string2</thing>
<thing>string3</thing>
<nested><thing>string1</thing></nested>
<nested><thing>string1</thing></nested>
<nested><thing>string2</thing></nested>
</data>
```

into the output

```
<list>
   <item>string1 string1 string1</item>
   <item>string2 string2</item>
   <item>string3</item>
</list>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'll see if I can use the grouping feature like this in my application.